# Within an AWS CLI command, add the ISO 8601 datetime

Tags: command-line, zsh, aws

As a fun side project, I'm building a serverless Todo application on AWS. I do a lot in the terminal, but my knowledge is basic.

The command to add something into my DynamoDB table via the AWS CLI (v2.3.4) is this:

```
aws dynamodb put-item \
    --table-name tasks \
    --item \
        '{"task_id": {"S": "3495353e-726f-4e0e-b290-8014c03be971"}, "user_id": {"S": "aae30f8e-aabe-4e38-918f-0f5a2223f589"}, "created_at": {"S": "2022-09-09T12:51:05Z"}, "content": {"S": "Clean car"}, "is_done": {"BOOL": false}}' \
    --profile personal
```

Notice that for `created_at` I'm manually typing in the ISO-8601 date as a string.

Now I know that on linux, in order to get the UTC datetime in the ISO-8601 format I need to run:

```
date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
```

My question is, how do I fit that into my DynamoDB `put-item` command so that I automatically/dynamically get the `created_at` from my linux system.

**What I have tried:**

I tried to simply plunk the `date` command into my DynamoDB command where the `created_at` value would go like this:

```
aws dynamodb put-item \
    --table-name tasks \
    --item \
        '{"task_id": {"S": "3495353e-726f-4e0e-b290-8014c03be971"}, "user_id": {"S": "aae30f8e-aabe-4e38-918f-0f5a2223f589"}, "created_at": {"S": date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"}, "content": {"S": "Clean car"}, "is_done": {"BOOL": false}}' \
    --profile personal
```

But that doesn't work. The command errors out and it returns with:

```
Error parsing parameter '--item': Invalid JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 138 (char 137)
JSON received: {"task_id": {"S": "3495353e-726f-4e0e-b290-8014c03be971"}, "user_id": {"S": "aae30f8e-aabe-4e38-918f-0f5a2223f589"}, "created_at": {"S": date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"}, "content": {"S": "Clean car"}, "is_done": {"BOOL": false}}
```

**Update:**

I just tried the `$(command)` method as suggested by Marcus, and I still get the invalid JSON error.

```
aws dynamodb put-item \
    --table-name tasks \
    --item \
        '{"task_id": {"S": "3495353e-726f-4e0e-b290-8014c03be971"}, "user_id": {"S": "aae30f8e-aabe-4e38-918f-0f5a2223f589"}, "created_at": {"S": "$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")"}, "content": {"S": "Clean car"}, "is_done": {"BOOL": false}}' \
    --profile personal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `jq` to insert the date into the json object:

```
aws dynamodb put-item \
    --table-name tasks \
    --item "$(
      jq -c '.created_at.S=(now|todate)' << 'EOF'
        {
          "task_id": {
            "S": "3495353e-726f-4e0e-b290-8014c03be971"
          },
          "user_id": {
            "S": "aae30f8e-aabe-4e38-918f-0f5a2223f589"
          },
          "created_at": {"S":""},
          "content": {
            "S": "Clean car"
          },
          "is_done": {
            "BOOL": false
          }
        }
EOF
     )" --profile personal
```

Also note that you can format dates in zsh without having to invoke `date`:

`${(%):-%D{%FT%TZ}}` expands to the current time in that format, though you'd have to set `TZ=UTC0` to get actual Zulu time. There's also a `strftime` builtin in the `zsh/datetime` module.

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick!

Comment: It should say *expands to the current **local** time in that format*. And adding a trailing `Z` is claiming that the time is UTC (Zulu) while that will only be true if the local time used is UTC. It is better to format as `${(%):-%D{%FT%T%Z%z}}`. In that way it will be clear what the timestamp means.

Comment: If I wanted to add a `modified_at` field to my `JSON`, how would change the command above Stephane?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message highlights, the JSON is invalid.

So, as to be expected, the command you wanted to be executed never was – how was the shell supposed to know which parts of the command line you wanted to pass unaltered, and which one you want executed?

If you want to substitute a command's output, use `$(command)`, e.g., `$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")`

Comment: Thanks Marcus, I must be missing something, cause even after trying your suggestion, I still get the same error about invalid JSON.

Comment: Here is a [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/F6Fx6Qr.png) that shows the syntax highlighting from zsh. It looks like it still doesn't recognise the `$(command)` format.

Comment: well, sure, within `'` it doesn't! You'll need to escape your JSON differently. It might really be easier to write the JSON to a file first, do a replacement on that, and use that.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to go the "JSON in a separate file" route cause I want to easily change values right from within the command. Hopefully someone know of a way to easily escape the JSON and make it work with the `$(command)`

Comment: As said, you simply can't use `'` to quote the string if you want anything within to be expanded. So, you need to use `"` as quoting, but then *all* the `"` within the JSON itself need to be escaped `\"`.

Comment: by the way, replacing can also be done on the command line, if that's a route you want to explore.